# Git and cloning

Tags: git

I have done an app for a client called 'A' (not really).

I have found out that it is very cool and that I want to sell it to other clients also. The directory 'A' is a Git repository. I think I have a problem with cloning it. As far as I can see I need to make a copy of the dir 'A' and call it 'Generic_A'. Then delete the dir 'A' and do a "git clone Generic_A A" Then I could start changing the 'Generic_A'-repo with a generic design and all client references removed. But that is kind of the other way around. I should have started doing the generic design and then cloned the repo to change to the client specific design.

Can I:

1. make a new branch
2. do all the changes to make the design generic
3. create a patch that reflects the changes between the two
4. remove the client specific branch
5. rename the directory to 'Generic_A'
6. clone the repo to a new dir 'A'
7. apply the patch to get the client specific stuff back

And if yes - how do I make the patch and apply it?

Regards,

Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could work, although between 6. and 7. I would make a 'client_A' branch before applying your patch.
The drawback is that you lose commit history specifics to client A, since you apply that patch in one big commit.

In your case, a patch can be made with [**`git diff`**](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html), see 
[patching with git diff](http://tamsler.blogspot.com/2009/02/patching-with-git-diff.html)

```
git diff --no-prefix > patchfile
```

> then apply the patch:

```
patch -p0 < patchfile
```

> If you have an existing "`git diff`" patch file that was created without the "--no-prefix" option, you can apply that patch via:

```
patch -p1 < patchfile
```

> this will ignore the default a/ b/ source prefixes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Why would you make the 'client_A' branch? Why not just apply the patch on the master branch? It is after all a clone of the generic one.

Comment: BTW - I know about loosing the history but I can live with that in this case.

Comment: @jriff: a ``client_A` branch allows you to leave the master branch alone, ready to be updated by your `Generic_A` master evolutions when you make the next `git pull`

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible work-flow :

- On A dir :

  - Create a new branch 'generic' from branch 'client-A'.
  - Use 'git rebase -i' on 'Generic' branch to remove all client A stuffs.
  - Use 'git rebase client-A generic' to rebase your client-A branch on the generic one.
- Rename your A dir to generic dir
- clone your generic dir to a new client-A dir
- remove client-A branch from generic dir.

This way, you will keep the history of the client-A branch.